# jquery append and appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to know if there is any difference (especially in terms of performance) between these two approaches:

1)

```
$('.container').append('<div class="divChild">test div</div>'); 
$('.container .divChild').click(function() { alert('test'); });
```

2)

```
var $childDiv = $('<div class="divChild">test div</div>');
$childDiv.appendTo($('.container')).click(function() { alert('test'); });
```

So basically the second approach seems to be much faster since I don't really have to search for the divChild div twice, but I need to add click event to the div.
Is that so?

Comment: You could make your first example more efficient by remembering the result of `$('.container')` and then using `children` on it, rather than repeating the search with a descendant selector: `var c = $('.container'); c.append(...); c.children('.divChild').click(...);`. I *suspect* (but don't know) that that would be the most efficient. Unless you're doing this thousands of times, it's unlikely to matter much.

Comment: I dont know about the speed, but the append sometimes fails, when adding data from ajax cal, dont know why!

Comment: I meant that in the first approach I kinda search for the div that I just added. Seems like bad code

Comment: @madhairsilence: `append` doesn't fail. Logic errors in the code using it may make it *seem* to fail...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unfortunately It did :(. could not find why! I just toggled between append and appendTo to confirm it!

Comment: @madhairsilence: Sorry, but I stand by my comment above. :-)

Comment: yeh.. Logically u r 735% right . But that was my experience. But it was long time ago! :P :P. Might try to replicate if possible!

Comment: You don't need `.appendTo($(...))`; you can just use `.appendTo(...)`.

Comment: If you cared about performance to that degree, you wouldn't be using jQuery in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point to make here is: Unless you're doing this a ***lot*** (thousands of times in a very short period of time), it's unlikely to matter.

But I would suspect the most efficient thing to do would be to remember the result of `$('.container')` and then use `children` on it:

```
var c = $('.container');
c.append('<div class="divChild">test div</div>'); 
c.children('.divChild').click(function() { alert('test'); });
```

Or actually, technically, you don't need the variable:

```
$('.container')
    .append('<div class="divChild">test div</div>')
    .children('.divChild')
      .click(function() { alert('test'); });
```

But I find long chains like that hard to read, hard to maintain, and hard to debug.

Comment: Better would be to use the event delegation of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/): `var class = 'divChild', html = "<div class="+class+">test div</div>"; $container.append(html).on('click', '.'+class, function() {});`.
Also there seems to be a [performance difference when using append/appendTo with the same context](http://jsperf.com/sdp-jquery-append/7), though I still can't conclude why.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
$('<div/>', {
    'class': 'divChild',
    'text': 'test div',
    'click': function(){
       alert('test');
    }
}).appendTo('.container');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SANMW/

Comment: I wonder what that translates to within the `$()` call. The jQuery source is so convoluted and spaghetti-like it's hard to tell without single-stepping it...

Comment: Yeah, looking at it, this ends up being a less-efficient version of the OP's Option 2. Not markedly less, not enough to matter, but less...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are correct, the jQuery source is very complex and yes it doesn't seem to be very efficient.